# Help with Permits and roles in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm looking for a way to implement permissions on Codeigniter
2 type users: Admin and User_basic, need an example or a library you can do. 
**ADMIN:** wide permissions. 
**User_basic:** only list. 
I have a table with users. 
1 table permissions. 
1  Table Roles.

All are related.

**NOTE: I have already implemented the login.**

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the class I usually use](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Permission_Class/)

It's easy to implement & you can see the example in the same link.